# C# - Can't access FileInfo from an external class

Tags: c#

I have:

```
namespace MyProgram
public class MyClass {
  FileInfo file = new FileInfo("text.txt");
}
```

Problem is that I can't access FileInfo from inside MyClass, but it works just fine in main() in Program.cs. I tried using System.IO.FileInfo but it doesn't work.

Comment: Aren't you missing parenthesis around the namespace? Or did you not post your actual code?

Comment: change FileInfo file = new FileInfo("text.txt"); to public FileInfo file = new FileInfo("text.txt");

Comment: `using System.IO;` (this isn't Java: using declaration, usually. bring in namespaces).

Answer (score 1):

You need to either use a using statement or use the full namespace.

```
using System.IO;

namespace MyProgram {
    public class MyClass {
        FileInfo file = new FileInfo("text.txt");
    }
}
```

or

```
namespace MyProgram {
    public class MyClass {
        System.IO.FileInfo file = new System.IO.FileInfo("text.txt");
    }
}
```